# How do I find the lowest AVERAGE of a subsection of a vector, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a very long column vector (20000 length). Within this list of 20000 values, I'd like to find 100 neighbouring values that yield the lowest average. I can imagine some kind of frame of 100 length that moves along the vector, with matlab computing all possible averages and then returning the lowest one.

The aim is - I want to find the smallest value in my vector, but prefer to find the smallest average value (using 100 as a sampling frame) to exclude the possibility of finding a low chunk of random noise.

A wordy problem, but any help appreciated.
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4):

> I can imagine some kind of frame of 100 length that moves along the vector, with matlab computing all possible averages

Use [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) with a vector of 100 equal values.

> and then returning the lowest one

Use [`min`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/min.html) for that. Its two outputs give you the minimum average and the index within the vector where those values start.

---

```
vector = rand(1,20000);
N = 100;
avg = conv(vector, ones(N,1), 'valid') / N; %// length is length(vector)-N+1
[lowestValue, lowestIndex] = min(avg);
```

Comment: Along the same lines, you could also use [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html): `avg = filter(ones(N,1)/N,1,vector);`. Either way, the "frame" that moves the length of the vector is known as a [boxcar filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function) and the process you want to do is called a moving average.